# Is there a way to get selected object in Django form?

Tags: python, django, forms

I'd like to get the Customer object (which is a foreign key selection) when it is selected. I want to be able to display attributes/fields of that customer when it is selected (and I want them to change if/when a different selection is made). I imagine I could use jquery to get the text and then query the db for the customer name. But if I have two customers with the same name I run into issues. So is there any way to grab that exact object that is selected?

To complicate things I am using django-autocomplete-light (which is awesome but may make this more difficult). But assuming this was a normal fk drop-down is there a way to get the object that the user selects?

[image]

EDIT:
Here is the html for the form:
[image]

EDIT 2:
Very close now - here is where it is updating the HTML. How do I get this?
[image]

Comment: The “value” of the selection will be its primary key so it should be unique

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that will be the case using auto-complete - can you take a look at my EDIT that includes the generated HTML?

Comment: Can you log the value of the select from your console? Are you using jquery? `document.getElementsByName("customer")[0].value`

Comment: That was very cool - it did return the id. But it only shows the id of the initial selection (there is one selected by default). The key: it does not display the new ID when I change the customer.

Comment: Is there an 'on selection' callback option for django widgets?

Comment: `$("#id_customer").select2().val()` or `$("#id_customer").val()`?

Comment: Can you see my EDIT2. I think we're very close. Thanks